# Could not verify password after hashing using PHP

Tags: php, hash

I have an issue. I am hashing my password using PHP but when I am verifying it its giving the following message.

> Notice: Undefined variable: liXZkG452 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/verify.php on line 2
>   Failed

I am explaining my code below.

**hash.php**

```
<?php
$password="subhra123@";
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo $hash;
?>
```

The above `echo` is giving this `$2y$10$liXZkG452/DQjB7TsIHEzuJ/ovi0L3.xwN1uYeqt.kFYma33Uu9Wq` value and again I am comparing it in the below file.

**verify.php**

```
<?php
$hash="$2y$10$liXZkG452/DQjB7TsIHEzuJ/ovi0L3.xwN1uYeqt.kFYma33Uu9Wq";
$password="subhra123@";
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'login';
}else{
    echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```

The above function is giving me the issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should use singlequotes `'` instead of double quotes. You have variable identifiers `$` in doublequotes, so PHP thinks its actually a variable. Using single quotes would circumvent that.

Comment: @Qirel  : perfect and thank you. What was the error May I know ?

Comment: Like I said, `$` is the variable identifier. So PHP thinks that anything after `$` is the variable-name. In double quotes, PHP uses variables, but not with single-quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its true.

Comment: you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use singlequpoted strings instead of doublequoted strings around your `$hash` variable, as PHP would interpret `$` as a variable-identifier inside doublequoted strings. Then it would assume that whatever comes next, is the variable name (which is why you get that "*Undefined variable..*" notice). The first two instances of `$` in the string won't be treated that way, because it's not a valid variable-name (it starts with a number).

The below would output "login", because the `$hash` now is quoted with singlequotes instead.

```
$hash = '$2y$10$liXZkG452/DQjB7TsIHEzuJ/ovi0L3.xwN1uYeqt.kFYma33Uu9Wq';
$password = "subhra123@";
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'login'; 
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

- [PHP.net on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
- [PHP.net on variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)